# phonegap, firebase, push notification

Tags: firebase, notifications, push, phonegap

I cannot get notifications from Firebase to appear. I followed the tutorial provided [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/push-notifications/). What could be the problem?

```
сode example : 
        setupPush: function() {
            var push = PushNotification.init({
                "android": {
                    "senderID": "966613396976",
                    "sound": true,
                    "vibration": true,
                    "badge": true
                },
                "browser": {},
                "ios": {
                    "sound": true,
                    "vibration": true,
                    "badge": true
                },
                "windows": {}
            });
            push.on('registration', function(data) {
                test(data);
                var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
                if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
                    localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId); 
                }  
            });
            push.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log("push error = " + e.message);
            });
            push.on('notification', function(data) {
                console.log('notification event');
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    data.message,         // message
                    null,                 // callback
                    data.title,           // title
                    'Ok'                  // buttonName
                );
           });
        }
    };
```

Comment: can you give feedback on the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a deprecated version of the Phonegap push plugin.
See this location for the newer version:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

This means that the init function should look like:

```
const push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        vibrate: true,
        sound: true
    },
    ios: {
        fcmSandbox: false,
        alert: true,
        vibrate:true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
    }
});
```

Please notice that the 'badge' parameter is not used in android. 
What's more is that you have to set a correct config.xml file:

This should be in there:

```
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="/google-services.json" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
  <resource-file src="push/GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</platform>

<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.0.0" source="npm" />
```

This only works with the right version:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md